# How to create multi ring donut pie chart using amcharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I want to make multi ring donut pie chart using AMCharts. Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say to make this kind of chart you're better off with a Gauge chart type where you can define separate [bands](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/GaugeBand) like in your example.

Here's a working code:

```js
var gaugeChart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "gauge",
  "axes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "tickAlpha": 0,
    "labelsEnabled": false,
    "startAngle": -150,
    "endAngle": 150,
    "bands": [{
      "color": "#8da44c",
      "endValue": 50,
      "startValue": 0,
      "radius": "100%",
      "innerRadius": "95%",
      "balloonText": "Lime one"
    }, {
      "color": "#ce0004",
      "endValue": 30,
      "startValue": 0,
      "radius": "90%",
      "innerRadius": "85%",
      "balloonText": "Red one"
    }],
    "endValue": 100
  }],
  "allLabels": [{
    "text": "3,000",
    "align": "center",
    "y": "45%",
    "size": 35
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/gauge.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: and how do i add text in middle of the chart

Comment: For example [Picture](http://res.cloudinary.com/dkeyb2ckj/image/upload/v1441088759/Untitled_nryvqy.png)

Comment: You could add any texts using Labels: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmAngularGauge#allLabels (I update my answer to show it)